# When to use Kotlin suspend keyword?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

```
fun startAsyncFunc() {
  launch {
    asyncFunc1()
    asyncFunc2()
  }
}

fun asyncFunc1() { ... }
suspend fun asyncFunc2() { ... }
```

I can finish the work without `suspend` and it even makes test easier (it can be tested without adding `runBlocking`.

My questions:

1. `asyncFunc1` vs `asyncFunc2`, which is better and why?
2. If `asyncFunc2` is better, should I always use `suspend` whenever a function will be ran in the coroutines?

#### Update

In the recent releases of Kotlin Coroutines, I notice if a method doesn't contain any coroutines code(like `launch`, `async`, etc), the compiler complains `This inspection reports a suspend modifier as redundant if no other suspend functions are called inside`. So I assume that `suspend` should be only used when it's a must.

#### Update2

[An advice from Google](https://youtu.be/ZTDXo0-SKuU?t=1112)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As a general rule of thumb, you should only declare your function `suspend` if the compiler forces you to.

One possible exception to this rule would be if you're defining this function as an open method (for instance in an interface) and you expect that some implementations/overrides will need to call suspending functions themselves.

It's important to note that both suspension and cancellation are *cooperative* in the coroutines world. This means that marking a function `suspend` doesn't do anything on its own. If you don't call suspending functions inside it, or check the cancellation status manually, it probably does more harm than good to mark it as `suspend` (because the machinery has a cost but you get no benefit from it in this case).

Most of the time, if you have a good reason for your function to be suspending, it means it's probably doing something that requires you to call suspending functions anyway. For instance, you might use `withContext` to switch to a particular thread pool, or you might wrap a callback-based function using `suspendCancellableCoroutine`. Either way, calling those functions would force you to add the `suspend` modifier to your function.

Also, note that declaring a function `suspend` does not enable your callers to do anything more than they could when your function was not suspending. If anything, you're limiting the use of your function.

Answer (score 15):

`suspend` keyword means coroutine can be suspended for later execution.

Having said that, you should consciously use it them for coroutines that will get suspended (e.q. your `asyncFunc2()` made a HTTP call and is awaiting response to process it)

So.

1. Use `suspend` for functions that will be delayed in some way (Awaiting some computations, api response etc.)
2. `suspend fun` can be run from coroutine only. So, if it gets suspended, it will block the coroutine. Take out the `suspend` keyword, but run it in coroutine and it will have the same effect. However, if you run this function from outside the coroutine, it will block the thread it was running on.

When testing coroutines, you should always invoke `runBlocking`. If you don't, a coroutine that gets suspended may not complete, resulting in a failed test.

Answer (score 2):

1. It depends. See the combination of the other two answers at this time: the effect of calling either function from a coroutine is identical. However, with the `suspend` keyword, the function itself can call other suspending functions. Using the keyword can be an indication of some work that requires time and therefore might need to suspend the calling coroutine.
2. A function that will always be called from a coroutine does not need to always have the `suspend` keyword. It only needs that keyword for the reasons given under 1. The other way around is true: a suspending function can only be called from a coroutine.

Answer (score 2):

Use suspend keyword for:

- functions that will be delayed in some way (awaiting some computations, Network Requests )

  - whenever the function calls other suspend functions
  - function that call withContext() – withContext() is a suspend function that comes from the Coroutine Library

The rule of the thumb is don’t mark a function suspend unless you are forced to

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/basics.html):

> Suspending functions can be used inside coroutines just like regular functions, but their additional feature is that they can, in turn, use other suspending functions, like delay in this example, to suspend execution of a coroutine.

Comment: What's the point in citing the official documentation without further explanation?