# Conceptual question regarding suspend and Deferred

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a question about when to use suspend and when not. My APIRepo class has a function like this -

```
override suspend fun retrieveDataFromRemote(): MyResult {
        if (utility.checkDeviceInternetConnection()) {
            try {
                val result = remoteInterface.getData().await()
                return ...
            } catch (t: Throwable) {
                return ...
            }
        } else {
            return ...
        }
    }
```

My Remote interface code looks like this -

```
@GET("/data/mydata")
fun getData(): Deferred<Response<MyModel>>
```

As you can see my `RemoteInterface` has no `suspend` keyword and returns a `Deferred`. This works totally fine. But when I add a `suspend` keyword to `getData()`, then I dont get the API response. Why is it like that? Does it have something to do with the `Deferred`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrofit 2.6.0 or newer has built-in `suspend` support.
Probably you are using `Kotlin Coroutine Adapter`. This library depends on reflection to detect whether the return type is `Deffered` or not. See [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-kotlin-coroutines-adapter/blob/e7f4d911b71d48a36950ca29ec6dfae9371e7959/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/retrofit2/adapter/kotlin/coroutines/CoroutineCallAdapterFactory.kt#L59).

Here is an example using Retrofit 2.6.0 :

```
interface RemoteInterface{

  @GET("/data/mydata")
  suspend fun getData(): MyModel
}
```

And in your ViewModel:

```
fun retrieveDataFromRemote() {
  viewModelScope.launch {
      val model = remoteInterface.getData()
      // do something with model
  }
}
```

Comment: So if I use Retrofit 2.6.0, I don't need to use Deferred? But how can I use await then?

Comment: a suspend function can be called in any other suspend fucntion or in a coroutine. see this blog post https://proandroiddev.com/suspend-what-youre-doing-retrofit-has-now-coroutines-support-c65bd09ba067

Comment: in your ViewModel you can do it like this: viewModelScope.launch { api.getData() }

Comment: I've added an example to the answer

Answer (score 0):

- When to use suspend and when not? You can refer to [suspend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54554753/when-to-use-kotlin-suspend-keyword)
- From Retrofit 2.6.0 or newer and it's built-in suspend support, not use Deferred

Comment: So if I use Retrofit 2.6.0, I don't need to use Deferred? But how can I use await then?

Comment: Example: @GET("users/{login}")
    suspend fun fetchUserDetailsAsync(@Path("login") login: String): User

Comment: Only change from Deferred to suspend,